# Multi-Input List Normalizing

Tags: python

I am in the process of learning python have been working through the 'loop' section. I am really stuck on this last zybooks lab and, to be honest, I have no clue where to start and could use a solution with explanation as I am really struggling with this section. Question Below, thanks in advance.

When analyzing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This adjustment can be done by normalizing to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers.

For this program, adjust the values by dividing all values by the largest value. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of floating-point values that follow.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:

```
print(f'{your_value:.2f}')
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
5
30.0
50.0
10.0
100.0
65.0
```

the output is:

```
0.30
0.50
0.10
1.00
0.65
```

The 5 indicates that there are five floating-point values in the list, namely 30.0, 50.0, 10.0, 100.0, and 65.0. 100.0 is the largest value in the list, so each value is divided by 100.0.

Comment: This is not a free coding service. Please see [ask]

Comment: what have you tried yet? what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: thank you both for your replies and I am sorry for the bad question. I was able to solve it with more tinkering and my solution is commented below.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the instruction, you should use a loop.

Assuming the following input:

```
text = '''5
30.0
50.0
10.0
100.0
65.0'''
```

```
# get the data as floats (skipping first number)
# you could also use a loop with `input`s if your coding server sends lines one by one
data = list(map(float, text.strip().split('\n')))[1:]

# calculate the maximum value
maximum = max(data)

# divide each element in list by maxium using a list comprehension (a compact kind of loop)
out = [e/maximum for e in data]
```

output: `[0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 1.0, 0.65]`

Comment: thank you for your reply! your answer is more efficient but it uses a lot of things I haven't learned yet. I was able to piece together my own solution. It is clunky but effective. Also, the  text is meant to be multiple inputs as opposed to providing a list

Answer (score 0):

```
nums=[]
num_nums=int(input())

for i in range(num_nums):
    val=float(input())
    nums.append(val)

max=max(nums)

for i in range(num_nums):
    print(f'{(nums[i]/max):.2f}')
```

this is the solution I came up with and it works. It uses the tools I have up to this point.

Comment: Don't use the variable `max` to store the output of `max(nums)`, else you will "break" the max builtin. You could do `max_num = max(nums)` instead

Comment: thank you for this feedback! the function worked in this case but I will remember this for the future as I have already submitted the lesson

Answer (score 0):

```
size = int(input())
inputList = []
for i in range(size):
    inputList.append(float(input()))
maxValue = None
for x in inputList:
    if maxValue==None or maxValue<x:
        maxValue = x
for x in inputList:
    print("%.2f"%(x/maxValue))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Poi lop. I know it can be hard to break into this community, but it's important to take the time to write good quality answers. Explain what your code does, and how it solves the problem.  Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer it will help you make valuable contributions to the site.